# Amazon AWS CLI not allowing valid JSON in payload parameter

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I am getting an error when I try and invoke a lambda function from the AWS CLI. I am using version 2 of the CLI.
I understand that I should pass the `--payload` argument as a string containing a JSON object.

```sh
aws lambda invoke --function-name testsms  --invocation-type Event --payload '{"key": "test"}' response.json
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid base64: "{"key": "test"}"
```

I have tried all sorts of variants for the JSON escaping characters etc. I have also tried to use the `file://test.json` option I receive the same error.

Comment: I copied the exact string above and it worked for me.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth: are you using version 2 of the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 147):

As @MCI said, AWS V2 defaults to base 64 input. For your case to work, simply add a `--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out` parameter to your command, so it'd be

```sh
aws lambda invoke --function-name testsms \
    --invocation-type Event \
    --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
    --payload '{"key": "test"}' response.json
```

Answer (score 31):

Looks like [awscli v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-binaryparam.) requires some parameters be base64-encoded.

> By default, the AWS CLI version 2 now passes all binary input and binary output parameters as base64-encoded strings. A parameter that requires binary input has its type specified as blob (binary large object) in the documentation.

The [payload parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html.) to `lamba invoke` is one of these `blob` types that must be base64-encoded.

> --payload (blob)
> The JSON that you want to provide to your Lambda function as input.

One solution is to use openssl base64 to encode your payload.

```sh
echo '{"key": "test"}' > clear_payload  
openssl base64 -out encoded_payload -in clear_payload
aws lambda invoke --function-name testsms  --invocation-type Event --payload file://~/encoded_payload response.json
```

Comment: Thanks I don't think I would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: Glad I could help :) consider marking my answer accepted! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks aws for making your complicated system ever more complicated

Comment: There is a typo at the last line: encoded_paylaod  -> encoded_payload

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, I have tried the following, which worked for me

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name testsms  --invocation-type Event --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload {\"key\": \"test\"} response.json
```

Note that, added `--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out` in the command and escaped " to \" in payload

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me and I find it simpler than having to remember/check the man page for the correct flags each time.

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name my_func --payload $(echo "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}" | base64) out
```

Comment: This is what I thought was easiest. Found this on the aws-cli issues as well. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4968

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, a string is a valid json.

In my case I had this problem

```
$ aws --profile diegosasw lambda invoke --function-name lambda-dotnet-function --payload "Just Checking If Everything is OK" out

An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized token 'Just': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"Just Checking If Everything is OK"; line: 1, column: 6]
```

and it turns out the problem was due to the AWS CLI trying to convert it to JSON. Escaping the double quotes did the trick

```
$ aws --profile diegosasw lambda invoke --function-name lambda-dotnet-function --payload "\"Just Checking If Everything is OK\"" out
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

Comment: note that actually it's due to how the shell works, not something aws-cli specific if you write `"toto tata"`   the `""` are used to understand that `toto tata`  is 1 argument , so bash will consume the `""` and give only `toto tata` to aws cli ,  which is not a valid json string.  So actually  `'"toto tata"'`  will work without escaping  as `''` will be consume by the shell and `"toto tata"` will given to your cli, which is a valid json

Answer (score 0):

On my windows PowerShell running LocalStack I had to use:

```
--payload '{\"key\": \"test\"}' response.json
```